# How to add multiple images in-line HTML in email body by iterating an ArrayList of images paths?

Tags: html, vb.net, email, html-email

I am trying to add in an email's HTML body some images by iterating through an `ArrayList` of image paths. One of them, the first image, it is added in HTML body, but the ones that come after they are being added as attachments with the ATT00X.jpg name. I find it strange. How can I have both images in the email's HTML body, one below the other?

The code below, maybe you guys can see the mistake in it:

```
 Dim mm As New MailMessage
 mm.Body = String.Format("")
 For i As Integer = 0 To imagespath.Count - 1
                Dim cale As String = imagespath(i).ToString()
                Dim img As LinkedResource = Nothing
                Try
                    img = New LinkedResource(cale, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
                    Dim strimage As String = "Image"
                    img.ContentId = strimage(i)
                    mm.Body = mm.Body & "<p>&nbsp;</p>"
                    mm.Body = mm.Body & "<td><img src=cid:" & img.ContentId & " alt=></td>"
                    mm.Body = mm.Body & "<p>&nbsp;</p>"
                    Dim av As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mm.Body, Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
                    av.LinkedResources.Add(img)
                    mm.AlternateViews.Add(av)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Log.Information(ex.Message)
                End Try
            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the rest but I see a potential problem here.

```
Dim strimage As String = "Image"
img.ContentId = strimage(i)
```

When you request strimage(i) you will get an iteration of the characters in "Image" as the loop continues.

```
I
m
a
g
e
```

Is this what you were expecting? It seems you could easily get an index out of range exception depending on `imagespath.Count`.

Also it would be better to use `List(Of String)` instead of an `ArrayList`.